# Custom UIRefreshControl with Lottie

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol, lottie

My goal is to replace the default spinner of the `UIRefreshControl` with a Lottie animation.

My issue is that the animation does not play immediately when I pull down my `UICollectionView` whose subview is the `UIRefreshControl`. The animation only plays when I scroll down slightly and pause my finger. The moment I again start moving the scrolling position it immediately goes back to its initial starting state not playing.

Any guidance would be appreciated, below is relevant code..

```
func setupRefreshControl() {
    guard let refreshContents = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RefreshControlView", owner: self, options: nil), let refreshView = refreshContents[0] as? RefreshControlView else { return }

    refreshView.frame = refreshControl.frame
    refreshControl.addSubview(refreshView)

    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(exampleFunction), for: .valueChanged)      
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for subview in refreshControl.subviews {
        if let refreshControlView = subview as? RefreshControlView {
            refreshControlView.activityIndicatorControl.animationView.setAnimation(named: "lottieJson")                
            refreshControlView.activityIndicatorControl.animationView.loopAnimation = true
            refreshControlView.activityIndicatorControl.animationView.play()
            break
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't see the animation playing while you are scrolling because every time `scrollViewDidScroll` is called you restart the animation by calling `play`. And because that function is called almost constantly while you scroll the animation does not have a chance to play more than its first frame. So it looks paused.

When implementing a custom Refresh Control you have to implement 3 phases:

**1. User scrolls but the refresh has not been triggered yet**

In this phase you probably want to show a progress in your animation depending on how far the user has scrolled. To do this you calculate the progress in `scrollViewDidScroll` and pass it to the `LOTAnimationView`'s `animationProgress` property.

To calculate this progress you have to know how far the user has to scroll down until the refresh is triggered. In my experience this happens at a `contentOffset.y` of approximately `150`.

**2. Refresh is triggered**

When the user has scrolled down enough a `.valueChanged` ControlEvent is triggered. When this happens you start the looping animation by calling `play()` on the `LOTAnimationView`

**3. Refresh is done**

When the refreshing is completed you call `endRefreshing()` on your custom Refresh Control. When this happens you stop the animation by calling `stop()` on the `LOTAnimationView`

Check out this small example of a LottieRefreshControl that I use in one of my projects:

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class LottieRefreshControl: UIRefreshControl {
fileprivate let animationView = Lottie.AnimationView(name: "searchAnimation")
fileprivate var isAnimating = false

fileprivate let maxPullDistance: CGFloat = 150

override init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setupView()
    setupLayout()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func updateProgress(with offsetY: CGFloat) {
    guard !isAnimating else { return }
    let progress = min(abs(offsetY / maxPullDistance), 1)
    animationView.currentProgress = progress
}

override func beginRefreshing() {
    super.beginRefreshing()
    isAnimating = true
    animationView.currentProgress = 0
    animationView.play()
}

override func endRefreshing() {
    super.endRefreshing()
    animationView.stop()
    isAnimating = false
}
}

private extension LottieRefreshControl {
func setupView() {
    // hide default indicator view
    tintColor = .clear
    animationView.loopMode = .loop
    addSubview(animationView)

    addTarget(self, action: #selector(beginRefreshing), for: .valueChanged)
}

func setupLayout() {
    animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        animationView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
        animationView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
    ])
}
}
```

Now you only have to call `updateProgress` on the Refresh Control from `scrollViewDidScroll`:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    refreshControl.updateProgress(with: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}
```